# Using a macro to filter a table regardless of its name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will filter data in tables, regardless of their table name. For example:

```
Sub Macro4()

Macro4 Macro

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        ">5", Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

This is a very simple code that filters a column of a table by a criteria. The code reads "Table2" so when I run it for another table with a different name, it gives me an error. How can I code it so it will filter any table regardless of its name?

Note that all my tables always have the same headers and amount of columns.

Okay: turns out I only need to change "Table1" for a 1. So that line would be ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)...
Is there a way to have that as default for my next Macro recordings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you only have 1 table per sheet, you can use this. It uses a count of the objects in the sheet and uses the first one, rather than the explicit named reference which doesn't work on other tables.

```
Sub Macro4()

Macro4 Macro

ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        ">5", Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

One improvement I would make is that you can avoid this section:

```
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B3").Select
```

by switching it to this, since the selections aren't really *doing* anything

```
    Columns("D:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make that change a default for my next Macro recording? or do I must go into the code and change that every time?

Comment: So first get this code into your module. Then right click the module and export it somewhere and save it. Then instead of typing it out or copy and paste, you can import the module into another file. If you mean sheet, make it a class module so it applies to all sheets or the workbook for the same result. I use class modules normally and haven't hit issues there. There's ways to have the macro added to your ribbon which would probably front end some work but save you time down the road so you don't need to open the developer tab each time.